# How do I work out the needed speed of the rotors in a Dual Gimbal CMG, as well as the needed tilt angle; for an object to maintain balance?

Tags: gyroscopes

I've been looking at methods of self-balancing an object and came across this: http://litmotors.com/c1/. I was wondering how one would calculate the needed speed of each rotor to rotate at, and the tilt angle of these rotors for it to maintain its balance? From what I understand the CMG works by changing the rotors spin axis and not its speed so it can maintain its balance, but what speed must it be rotating at to do this? (I imagine its related to the mass of the object and angular momentum in relation to the angle of the object).

For the second part of my question I was wondering how I would calculate the needed change of in the tilt of the rotors? Would this be as simple as working out the opposite angle as the one the object is leaning, as this would move its angular momentum in the opposite direction from it falling? This is what sense I can make from the research I've done, but definitely correct me and send me in the right direction if wrong.

I'm asking this as I am exploring whether it would be possible to put a system like this into a push scooter to make it self-balancing.

Comment: This question seems like it may get better responses on the [Engineering Stack Exchange](http://engineering.stackexchange.com/)